# Protractor in STS IDE -> Could not find update-config.json

Tags: javascript, json, protractor, webdriver, webdriver-manager

Currently I have Protractor v.5.1.1, Node.js v.6.10.0

All protractor tests work in window console but when I try to run them from STS IDE I get below error. Of course i did 'webdriver-manager update' but it doesn't help at all. Does anyone has an idea how to resolve this problem?

Below the error respectively when I use or do not 'directConnect'

```
[22:21:48] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[22:21:48] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[22:21:48] E/direct - Error code: 135
[22:21:48] E/direct - Error message: Could not find update-config.json. Run    'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.
[22:21:48] E/direct - Error: Could not find update-config.json. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.
at IError  (D:\STS_workspace\jgh\node_modules\protractor\built\exitCodes.js:5:1)
at ProtractorError (D:\STS_workspace\jgh\node_modules\protractor\built\exitCodes.js:10:9)
at BrowserError (D:\STS_workspace\jgh\node_modules\protractor\built\exitCodes.js:51:9)
at Direct.getNewDriver (D:\STS_workspace\jgh\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\direct.js:62:31)
at Runner.createBrowser (D:\STS_workspace\jgh\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:194:43)
at q.then.then (D:\STS_workspace\jgh\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:338:29)
at _fulfilled (D:\STS_workspace\jgh\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (D:\STS_workspace\jgh\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (D:\STS_workspace\jgh\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
at D:\STS_workspace\jgh\node_modules\q\q.js:556:49
[22:21:48] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 135
```

or

```
[21:19:23] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[21:19:23] E/local - Error code: 135
[21:19:23] E/local - Error message: No update-config.json found. Run    'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.
[21:19:23] E/local - Error: No update-config.json found. Run 'webdriver- manager update' to download binaries.
   at IError (D:\STS_workspace\jgh\node_modules\protractor\built\exitCodes.js:5:1)
   at ProtractorError (D:\STS_workspace\jgh\node_modules\protractor\built\exitCodes.js:10:9)
   at BrowserError (D:\STS_workspace\jgh\node_modules\protractor\built\exitCodes.js:51:9)
   at Local.addDefaultBinaryLocs_ (D:\STS_workspace\jgh\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\local.js:40:23)
   at Local.setupDriverEnv (D:\STS_workspace\jgh\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\local.js:81:14)
   at Local.setupEnv  (D:\STS_workspace\jgh\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\driverProvider.js:110:34)
   at q.then (D:\STS_workspace\jgh\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:334:41)
   at _fulfilled (D:\STS_workspace\jgh\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
   at self.promiseDispatch.done    (D:\STS_workspace\jgh\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
   at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch     (D:\STS_workspace\jgh\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
[21:19:23] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 135
```

My conf.js looks like:

```
var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;

exports.config = {
  //    directConnect:true,
  specs: ['spec4.js'],
 framework: 'jasmine2' ,

 onPrepare: function () {
  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
  spec: {
    displayStacktrace: true,
    displaySuccessesSummary: true,
    displayFailuresSummary: true,  
    displayPendingSummary: true,
    displaySpecDuration: true,     
      },

    }));
  },

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 25000,
    print: function () {},
},
```

I don't have selenium folder in the path   node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager but I have package.json where I added "webdriver-update": "webdriver-manager update".
                                                                                        This is the output of npm run webdriver-update:

```
    D:\STS_workspace\jgh>npm run webdriver-update
    npm WARN invalid config proxy="http:"  
    npm WARN invalid config Must be a full url with 'http://'
    npm WARN invalid config proxy="http:"
    npm WARN invalid config Must be a full url with 'http://'
    npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
    npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program     Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "webdriver-update"
    npm ERR! node v6.10.0
    npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
    npm ERR! path D:\STS_workspace\jgh\package.json
    npm ERR! code ENOENT
    npm ERR! errno -4058
    npm ERR! syscall open
    npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\STS_workspace\jgh\package.json'
    npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\STS_workspace\jgh\package.json'
    npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
    npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
    npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\STS_workspace\jgh\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: What is your script for `npm run webdriver-update`? The root problem is you are not downloading your binaries.

Comment: Just started seeing this too.. did you solve it?

Comment: BTW I solved my issue. Turns out that if I add: `npm set unsafe-perm=true` my scenario works. I don't know if this is the same scenario as yours though. let me know and if it is I'll publish an answer.

Answer (score 54):

It looks like you are either using `directConnect` or launching with a `local` driver provider (not having `seleniumAddress` or `directConnect`) in your configuration file. You need to run `webdriver-manager update`.

Previously I had extra flags to not download standalone or gecko with `webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false`. This is no longer the case if you are starting via a local driver provider. You will need the selenium standalone jar file.

You could run this with a script in package.json. Something like:

```
"scripts": {
  "webdriver-update": "webdriver-manager update"
}
```

Then execute this with: `npm run webdriver-update`. How do you check if the binaries are there? In your project, navigate to `node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/`. This is where the `update-config.json` and your downloaded binaries are located.

Comment: -> unfortunatelly it  is not my problem. I dont use directConnect. Anyway a tried your idea but still doesnt help :(

Comment: You are using direct connect because it says so in your error log. Maybe you should add your configuration file to your question

Comment: Okej, my mistake sorry because once I used and once not 'directConnection' but anyway I still get the error :(
I updated my question - could you acquaint with it , please?

Comment: Please see the updated answer. Also, since it sounds like your binaries are not being downloaded, please also include your `npm run webdriver-update` console output.

Comment: The above answer worked for me, even though I was in different but similar situation. Calling "npm test" failed with the same error, even after running "webdriver-manager update" many many times. However calling "protractor config.js" directly from command line succeeded. The reason was the same root cause as described here: npm must run "webdriver-manager update" to get selenium files locally in the local project's node_modules folder. When running "webdriver-manager update" directly, it installed the selenium files globally only.

Comment: Yes calling npm test would require that Protractor is a node dependency in your package.json. If Protractor is installed globally and not part of the package.json, this won't work because Protractor is not part of your local node_modules folder

Answer (score 52):

You can try to update it like this, it will definitely update it in node_modules/protractor :

```
$ ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update
```

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me in my Protractor framework on OSX.

Answer (score 23):

Just execute [webdriver-manager](https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager) with [npx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx) command in your project folder;

```
npx webdriver-manager update
```

Comment: Thanks @Yildiray-Meric
Was the only solution that worked!

Answer (score 2):

On MacOS, I resolved this error by adding the seleniumAddress to my Protractor config file (I was previously using directConnect, so commented that out):

```
// directConnect: true,
// baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4000/',
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/',
```

I now start Protractor server by running: `$ webdriver-manager start`

And in a different terminal window, I start tests with: `$ ng e2e`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to run this command and it fixes it - `npm run webdriver-update` it updates you webdriver in node_modules section under `node_modules/protractor`.

These 2 lines are the main culprits. Just try running that command and it should fix your issue.

```
[22:21:48] E/direct - Error message: Could not find update-config.json. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.
[22:21:48] E/direct - Error: Could not find update-config.json. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I ran npx webdriver-manager update command directly inside

$\node_modules\protractor\bin and it started working as expected.

traverse to the above mentioned folder inside your e2e and run command.

Answer (score 0):

When I installed Java and updated Java Path in Windows 10, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case

```
npm run webdriver-manager update
```

updates only `app\node_modules\webdriver-manager` and not `app\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\`. No matter if I run that command directly from console or as package.json script.
I had to run

```
npx webdriver-manager update
```

inside `app\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\`.

Another solution would be this script:

```
"postinstall": "node ./node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager update"
```

Answer (score 0):

With this I am able to proceed further
node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update