# How to run individual Angular/Jasmine test cases in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, jasmine

My `angular` code is organised into separate directories, one for each component. Each component has its corresponding `spec.ts`. How do I run specs from only one particular file using `IntelliJ`. It is not practical to mark each test case as `fdescribe` and `fit`. Is there a menu option which can let me do it?

Comment: what test runner do you use? For karma or jest, for example, you can run individual tests using test markers in the left gutter or use *Run* command in file right-click menu to run all tests from the current file

Comment: Thanks. Tried but getting error - `"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "...\nav-component.component.spec.ts" "--grep=^NavComponentComponent "
(node:24240) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
[16:20:24] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[16:20:24] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[16:20:24] E/direct - Error code: 135
[16:20:24] E/direct - Error message: Could not find update-config.json. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.`

Comment: I was able to move forward using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42426549/protractor-in-sts-ide-could-not-find-update-config-json  but now I am stuck with error `session not created: Chrome version must be between 71 and 75`. My chrome version is 76. Any idea how I can make Protractor work on version 76?

Comment: Please see https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5289 for some hints