# e2e - Error code: 135 - Could not find chromedriver at null. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries

Tags: node.js, angular, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running `ng e2e --no-webdriver-update` and getting this error:

> C:\project\Angular>ng e2e --no-webdriver-update
>       [12:13:05] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
>       [12:13:05] E/direct - Error code: 135
>   [12:13:05] E/direct - Error message: Could not find chromedriver at null. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.
>   [12:13:05] E/direct - Error: Could not find chromedriver at null. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.
>       at Direct. (C:\project\Angular\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\direct.js:74:31)
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at C:\project\Angular\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\direct.js:7:71
>       at new Promise ()
>       at __awaiter (C:\project\Angular\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\direct.js:3:12)
>       at Direct.getNewDriver (C:\project\Angular\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\direct.js:57:16)
>       at Runner. (C:\project\Angular\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:190:53)
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at C:\project\Angular\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:7:71
>       at new Promise ()
>   [12:13:05] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 135
>   An unexpected error occurred: undefined

Running `webdriver-manager update`doesn't solve the issue.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42426549/protractor-in-sts-ide-could-not-find-update-config-json) issue wasn't the same but gave some information.

EDIT:
If I run `ng e2e` without `--no-webdriver-update` I get this error:

> C:\project\Angular>ng e2e
>   Cannot automatically find webdriver-manager to update.
>   Update webdriver-manager manually and run 'ng e2e --no-webdriver-update' instead.
>   Error: Cannot automatically find webdriver-manager to update.
>   Update webdriver-manager manually and run 'ng e2e --no-webdriver-update' instead.
>       at ProtractorBuilder._updateWebdriver (C:\project\Angular\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\protractor\index.js:92:23)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.rxjs_1.of.pipe.operators_1.concatMap [as project] (C:\project\Angular\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\protractor\index.js:32:200)

See [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5209) for more information.

Comment: You could be updating webdriver-manager and launching protractor in different scopes. Could you share both command you are using?

Comment: I'm trying to run my e2e tests using: `ng e2e --no-webdriver-update`

Comment: Why are you setting `--no-webdriver-update` flag?

Comment: see edit above, if I run without the flag, it gives an error which says to use the flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen a similar issue before and to troubleshoot it it's important to remember some things.

Node package like protractor can be installed at two scopes: globally on the machine and locally inside a Node project. The same goes for webdriver-manager. Whenever Protractor is installed a version of Webdriver-manager will be installed at the same time and at the same scope.

If you have webdriver-manager installed at two scopes then it is possible to update the files in one successfully but accidentally be launching protractor from the other.

When `webdriver-manager update` runs it download some files into the webdriver folder. This is an example of the folder structure to a local installation of webdriver-manager.

```
C:\ProtractorProjects\ddg\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager
```

Here is a screenshot of that folder. The selenium file is essentially what gets created when `webdriver-manager update` runs. It contains the browser drivers required by your tests.

**Screenshot of webdriver folder**
[image: Screenshot of webdriver folder]

**Screenshot of selenium folder**

[image: Screenshot of selenium folder]

---

**Update webdriver locally using cmd:** `node_modules\.bin\webdriver-manager update`

**Update webdriver globally using cmd:** `webdriver-manager update`

---

Can you check the relevant folder before and after a `webdriver-manager update command` and that may help you troubleshoot further